# visibility of ASP.NET label on Required Field Validator

Tags: javascript, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

I have an asp.net label which is invisible.
When i insert something in DB i set it to `visible=true` with a message "Record saved"
 and it remains visible until another server side event is not fired.
But the problem is that When i click on insert again wit empty fields required field validator invokes and gives message like

```
Please fill all the fields.
Record saved.
```

Comment: You could use a `ValidatorCalloutExtender` to use a "popup" to show the error-message or a `ValidationSummary` to list all  validation errors where you want.

Comment: How about on insert-click, add a javascript function that hides that label?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to the bottom of your page

```
<body>
   <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1"></asp:Label>



    <script>
        //hide the label after 3 seconds
        window.setTimeout(function(){
              document.getElementById('<%= Label1.ClientID %>').style.display = 'none';
        }, 3000);

    </script>

</body>
```

And remember to set it visible from code-behind when needed again

Comment: What if the user misses the message because they were staring at the ceiling? That's a little kludgey.

Answer (score 0):

Just hide the label on the client side when the user clicks the insert button

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnInsert" OnClientClick="hideLabel();"  OnClick="btnInsert_OnClick" ValidationGroup="InsertValidation" CausesValidation="True" />

<script>
    function hideLabel(){
          document.getElementById('<%= Label1.ClientID %>').style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void btnInsert_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Visible = true;
}
```